# Filling out create form with values from a list/dict using webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I've located all inputs on a create form with on my application by:

```
_inputs =find_elements_by_xpath("//form[@id='createForm']//input")
```

and I got my list of values that I need to input :

```
_data = ['selenium', 'selenium test', 'John Dow']
```

what I'd like to do is to send keys to each of those webelements from list using a loop, what I wrote

```
for x in range(len(self._data)):
    try:
        _inputs[x].send_keys(self._data[x])
    except Exception:
        continue
    finally:
        _all_inputs[0].send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

sending RETURN should trigger the submission of the form

but I'm getting `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

When I'm sending keys individually it's not an issue but well that's not what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [visibility_of](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of) from `expected_conditions` to make sure the element is visible

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for x in range(len(self._data)):
    try:
        wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of(_inputs[x]))
        _inputs[x].send_keys(self._data[x])
    except Exception:
        continue
    finally:
        _all_inputs[0].send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```